# Auto rebuild docker container after any code change

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running two containers using `docker-compose`. Is there an option to force docker-compose to rebuild and to run the container after any code change? If so, I would like to get an example. If it isn't possible, is there a workaround for that case?

Comment: Just `docker-compose down`, `docker rmi <image>`, `docker-compose up` when a code change happens (assuming the `docker-compose` also builds the image if needed)?

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I need to do automation for this process.

Comment: How do you detect a code change? If you code is kept with Git, there are Git hooks.

Comment: Detect the change the change in some way and run the mentioned commands. The easiest example you know you changed the code and just run those commands.

Comment: So actually i need to write an external script? Is it the only option?